# Adding characters to the beginning and end of a string?

Tags: vb.net, string

Evening everyone, first timer here, I have tried to research this as best as I could but to no avail. Probably because I'm still rough on the terminology.

Basically I am trying to add a pair of [[ and ]] to a string ( in Visual Studio 2015 using VB), the [[ at the beginning and the ]] at the end, but only if the user has put something into the string, if its blank the [[ ]] aren't needed and will throw up errors with what I'm doing if they're present.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Here is what I tried

```
If txtDamage.Text = "" Then
        dMacro1 & txtDamage.Text & dMacro2
    ElseIf
        txtDamage.Text = " "
    End If
```

Comment: Hi Zack, welcome to SO. Show us the code you tried

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! Edited it to show what I've most recently tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your post several times I guess I have an idea what you want.

```
If Not txtDamage.Text = "" Then
   txtDamage.Text = "[[" & txtDamage.Text & "]]"
End If
```

This should do it. Correct me if I interpret your question wrong.

Comment: Thou art my savior! This worked like a charm! I appreciate the help a ton.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check [Not](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cwcswt4.aspx) operator while checking string is empty or not.

**Tried this:**

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDamage.Text) Then
        dMacro1 & txtDamage.Text & dMacro2
End If
```

Comment: I tried this but it was much easier using GrindelOh's, declaring Dims for the [[ ]] wasn't needed I guess lol